# Apachesolr drupal facets breaks in multiple lines

Tags: drupal-6, solr, facet

I am using apachesolr module in drupal
I have created a custom facet field **subject** but in drupal facet block, the sentence is breaking in multiple line/result
for example the **subject** Analytical chemistry would be
`<int name="analyt">1</int>

<int name="chemistri">1</int>`

I have tables journal, subject, subject_journal and article
My data config file has entity

```
<entity name="subject" pk="id"
                    query="select s.id, s.title from subject s
                            join subject_journal sj on sj.subject_id = s.id
                            join article a on a.journal_id = sj.journal_id
                            where sj.journal_id = '${article.journal_id}' 
                            group by s.id, s.title">
                    <field column="id" name="subject_id" /> 
                    <field column="title" name="subject" />                         
        </entity>
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be performing analysis on your facet field.

General facet field detail -

Faceting fields are often specified to serve two purposes, human-readable text and drill-down query value, they are frequently indexed differently from fields used for searching and sorting:

They are often not tokenized into separate words
They are often not mapped into lower case
Human-readable punctuation is often not removed (other than double-quotes)
There is often no need to store them, since stored values would look much like indexed values and the faceting mechanism is used for value retrieval.

you should maintain a seperate copy for the facet field and perform no analysis on it, and use that as the facet field.

```
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<!-- Maintain different facet field -->
<field name="subject_facet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<!-- copy field -->
<copyField source="subject" dest="subject_facet"/>
```

Comment: Thanks patel  I  have other entities and their faceting working fine and I didnt use that approach you specified above  like journal facet fied <entity name="journal" pk="id"
                        query="select issn, title from journal where id = '${article.journal_id}'">
      <field column="issn" name="issn" />
      <field column="title" name="journal_title" />      
   </entity>

Comment: If you are using text as the field type and the field has multiple words or produces tokens, you would have this issue. For facet you need string as the field type. and btw its Patil and not Patel

Comment: Thanks its working i have changed the type from text to string   <field name="subject" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> but i have to pass &facet=true although it is already true in configuration if i didnt specify  &facet=true in my search url it shows me the subject with spellin mistake any thoughts

Comment: I have to pass http://localhost/search/apachesolr_search/continuity&facet=true but if pass  http://localhost/search/apachesolr_search/continuity this will show me the subject facet with spelling mistake

Comment: not really sure for this one. If facet=true is not passed you wont get back any facet response.

Comment: 'facet' => 'true', already set in apachesolr_search_basic_params in apachesolr_seacrh.module its also show true, when i debug $params

Comment: hmm .not sure for the spelling mistake then. you may want to provide more information. Also if the answer worked for you might also want to accept it.